# constructible sheaves not defined over the base field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, l-adic-sheaves

Let $k$ be a finite field, $X$ a smooth variety over $k$, and $D^b_c(X)$ the bounded derived category of complexes of $\ell$-adic sheaves with constructible cohomology sheaves. Let now $\bar{k}$ be an algebraic closure of $k$ and $X_{\bar{k}}$ the extension of scalars of $X$.

Question: How do the objects of $D^b_c(X_{\bar k})$ that are not defined over any finite extension of $k$ (i.e. that do not come by pullback from $D^b_c(X_{k'})$ for any finite extension $k'/k$) look like?

Comment: Is it obvious that such objects exist?

Comment: Not at all for me, but there are many places in the literature where the author restrict to the subcategory of those, that's why I'm trying to understand...